# Can't send file

Tags: c, file, serial-port, send

I'm making a project where I have to implement a Stop-and-Wait protocol. I'm trying to send the frames to another computer but my function to send isn't working. The code is bellow. If you need to see any more code, please let me know. I just wrote here what thought was most important for the problem.

This is my function for sending the frame, it is supposed to read the info from the file and split it into frames and add other information of the frame to each frame. This part is working nice, the problem is when I try to send frame by frame, it just doesn't do it. If I print temp it prints fine.

```
void sendFrame()
{
    char *buf;
    char* filename = "mytext.txt";
    struct stat tr;
    stat(nomefich, &tr);
    int size = tr.st_size;
    FILE *fi = fopen(filename,"rb");
    buf = malloc(size);
    fread(buf,size,1,fi);
    fclose(fi);

    //printf("%s",buf);

    char *buffer=(char *)malloc(256*sizeof(char));

    char *source=buf;
    char *dst=buffer;
    char *src=source;
    char *end=source+strlen(source);


    while(src<=end)
    {
        strncpy(dst,src,255);

        src +=255;
        dst[256]='\0';
        char *temp;
        temp=dados(dst);
        char *confir;
        do{
            char *frameTemp;
            printf("%s",temp);
            send(temp);
            confir=getConf();
        }while(confir!="TRUE");
    }
}
```

And this is my function send that sends an array:

```
    void send(char *frame)
{
    int port;
    port=open_port();
    sendData(frame,strlen(frame),port);
    close(port);
}
```

And this is sendData() that sends character by character an array to the serial port:

```
void sendData(char *buffer, int size, int port) 
{
    int aux = 0;
    while(aux != size){
        write(port, &buffer[aux], sizeof(char));
        aux ++;
    }
}
```

The functions send() and sendData() seem to be working fine. The problem is on sendFrame(), I think

Comment: "isn't working" and "just doesn't work" are not statements that can help anyone debug a problem.  One thing I see is why do you open and close the port for each message?  That can't be helping anything.  Leave the port open and send a message, wait for a response, and repeat until you've sent the whole thing, and then close the port.

Comment: this line: stat(nomefich, &tr); should probably be: if( 0 < stat( filename, &tr ) ) {perror("stat"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

Comment: if the size of the data were to change, you would have to search you code and change it in several places.  Much better to have #define FRAME_LENGTH (255) and use the definition in all places in the code.  Even the 256 value would become FRAME_LENGTH+1

Comment: what if (end - src) < 255 or strlen(source) < 255 ?